# LACP implementation, what's the right socket to use?

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I'm new using sockets.

I must implement under linux environment, in user space, the LACP protocol. Each computer sends periodically for each ethernet interface a control message, a structure LACPDUs. 
What would be the best family of sockets to get them to communicate(RAW, PACKET, TCP, UDP)? The socket send / receive must be of the same type?

My application already sends well the LACPDUs, but the application on the other side does not receive them ( I was capturing with wireshark, it captures the packets, but dont reach the application).

This is how i created the sockets:

**Send paquet: (this works ok, even without binding)**

```
int sock, sent;
struct sockaddr sa;
if (sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_PACKET, htons(ETH_P_SLOW))<0)   //sockfd = socket(int socket_family, int socket_type, int protocol);        
        {perror("error socketsalida\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}
sa.sa_family = AF_INET;
strcpy(sa.sa_data, iface);
if((sent = sendto(sock, data, len, 0, &sa, sizeof(sa))) <= 0)
               {perror("error sendto\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}
close(sock);
```

**Receive packet: (this doesnt work)**

```
int received, sockrec;
struct sockaddr sa;
struct LACPDU buffer;

socklen_t addrlen = sizeof (sa);
sockrec = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_PACKET, htons(ETH_P_SLOW));
if (sockrec<0) {perror("Error receiver socket\n");exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}
if ((received = recvfrom(sockrec, &buffer, BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&sa, &addrlen)) < 0)
        {perror("Errorrecvfrom\n");exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}

close (sockrec);
```

Any ideea? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you need to send Layer 2 packets, packet sockets are the correct choice. Beware that the `AF_INET/SOCK_PACKET`-combination you use has been deprecated a long time ago. Use `AF_PACKET` as the socket domain and either `SOCK_RAW` or `SOCK_DGRAM` as the type. Using the `sendto`/`recvfrom`-calls is the right way to go about this, but your initializion is mostly wrong.

I suggest you take a look at existing code (like [this](http://saju.net.in/code/misc/arp.c.txt)) that uses packet sockets to see how it can be done. I also recommend a look at the manpage `packet(7)` (see [here](http://linux.die.net/man/7/packet)).

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot, i will try this way and then i'll post the results.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure but I think you need to bind to that socket in the receiver before you can recvfrom. It works just fine on the sender because you're just sending but the receiver doesn't know where to grab it from. So use bind and see if that works.

Disclosure: I'm not familiar with LACP protcol.

Answer (score 0):

LACP is a layer 2 (data link layer) protocol. Your code is trying to send LACP frames as UDP packets, which will not have any effect.

Your code is specifically not working because you aren't fully filling out your `struct sockaddr` in the sending code, and aren't binding the socket in the receiving code. However, this approach won't work at all for actual LACP packets; you will probably need to use raw sockets.